# ASP Classic on IIS7 Cannot create COM Object

Tags: com, iis-7, asp-classic

I am getting permission denied errors when trying to create a com object in asp. The com object is a VB6 dll that has been registered. Procmon does not show any permission errors. I have granted permissions to the folder that contains the dll to the AppPool user and well as the authenticating user (IUSR). I noticed that there are a few people experiencing this problem with no definite solution. Please help!!

Comment: Which operational system, 32 or 64 bits ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should check is that the permissions you have assigned to the folder have cascaded to the dll.  I've seen a few cases like this where the dll had its own independent ACL rather than inheriting anything from its folder.

Comment: I have checked and the dll's have the required permissions. The strange thing is that ProcMon does not report any permissions errors.

Comment: @yuben:  Try creating a do nothing class in VB6 and see if you can instance that.  I'm wondering if there is something in the construction of the COM object (that is in the VB code) that is failing due to permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In procmon, can you see a successful read of HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID{YOUR_COMPONENT_CLASS_ID} ?

Maybe you have issues with rights in registry key associated to your component.

For a list of registry keys involved, please see the [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690440%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Best

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I have this working now. It was related to a another COM dll that was being called from the VB6 dll. However, I used to be able to step into VB6 from ASP/IIS6 but this now fails with a permissions error again. I will post another question for this. Thanks.